# App fails to launch on testing device with higher API

Tags: android, gradle, android-activity, crash

I have an android app that runs just fine on my testing device(`API 17`). However, when I run the same app on a device with a higher `API`(In this case `22`) the app fails to launch.

All these devices are real devices not *emulators*

```
    02/19 11:10:07: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.user.eafya/com.example.user.eafya.activities.FirstActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n 
"com.example.user.eafya/com.example.user.eafya.activities.FirstActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.user.eafya/.activities.FirstActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.user.eafya/com.example.user.eafya.activities.FirstActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

First activity is the  launcher activity inside the manifest file.

Here is the `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.eafya"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.0.0-RC1.jar')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

The manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.eafya">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".activities.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.FirstActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ClinicalHistory"
            android:label="LOG IN" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="LOG IN" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddAllergy" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ClinicalHistoryDetailActivity"
            android:label="LOG IN" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Appointments" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Allergies"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_allergies"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MedicalTips"
            android:label="News" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MedicalDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Wallet" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MapsActivityCurrentPlace"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddChronics" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AllergyDetail"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add manifest entry of `FirstActivity`.

Comment: `The launcher activity is declared in the manifest` what do you mean by this? is the launcher activity first activity

Comment: `App crash` - it doesn't crash. As you said, `the app fails to launch`

Comment: Also try to pass the APK file to device, and install it from the device manually

Comment: yes. First activity is the launcher activity

Comment: @VladMatvienko thanks for the suggestion. "App is not installed" is what I get.

Comment: Share your Manifest. Most likely there is no entry of `FirstActivity` there.

Comment: @SrikarReddy I have edited and shared my Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the contribution. Here is what I found. I changed the launcher activity to another activity other than "FirstActivity" and that failed too but at least it gave me an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
```

After changing the primary colour(using the colour pallet located at colors.xml) to completely opaque, everything worked.

I had adjusted the transparecy of the primary and primaryDark and this seems to have been the issue.